# Angularfire2 - retrieve added object

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I'm trying to find a complete example that uses angularfire2 but I can't find one. Some examples uses anugalrfire2 with native firebase or an old version of angularfire.

I have some questions about how to use angularfire2/database to create two documents with dependencies.

Example

Database:

```
locations { 
 country: string
 lat: number
 long: number
 .....
}

stores {
 name: string
 locationID: string
 description: string
  .....
}
```

So tried to find a way to create one `location` and one `store` in a atomic creation if possible, without luck. Then, after I could update `newStore.locationID = newLocation.id`

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
....
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

createStore(ownerID: number, storeData: Store, locationData: Location) {        

    let promises = {
        newStore: this.db.object('/stores').add(storeData),
        newLocation: this.db.object('/locations').add(locationData),
    }

    Observable.forkJoin(promises).subscribe((r) => {
        newStore.userID = ownerID;
        newStore.workingRegionID = newLocation.key;
    });
}
```

I also tried to create an empty Store (using AngularFire2), but I didn't find a way to do this. (received all types of error)

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
....
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

createStore(ownerID: number, storeData: Store, locationData: Location) {

    let newStoreKey = this.db.object('/stores').push().key;
    let newLocationKey = this.db.object('/locations').push().key;

    storeData.userID = ownerID;
    storeData.workingRegionID = newLocationKey;

    let sets = {};
    sets['/stores/' + newStoreKey] = Store;
    sets['/locations/' + newLocationKey] = Location;

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.db.set(sets));
}
```

Finally, I have some questions about atomicy and rules.

1. Do I need to use Firebase's Transactions to make it atomic?
2. AngularFire2 retrive rules from Firebase? If not, can I set/update info offline and when I came online Angular could fire an write exception? How can I should handle this in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was close from a valid answer. That what I got in my [storeService](https://github.com/makah/rateSiteFirebase/blob/master/src/app/services/store.service.ts)

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
....
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

createStore(ownerID: string, storeData: Store, locationData: Location) {
    let newStore = this.db.list('/stores').push(undefined);
    let newStoreKey = newStore.key;
    let newLocation = this.db.list('/stores').push(undefined);
    let newLocationKey = newLocation.key;
    storeData.ownerID = ownerID;
    storeData.workingRegionID = newLocationKey;
    storeData.name = storeData.name.toLowerCase();

    let tasks = {};
    tasks["/stores/" + newStoreKey] = storeData;
    tasks["/locations/" + newLocationKey] = locationData;

    return this.db.object('/').update(tasks);
}
```

Answering my own questions.

Q: Do I need to use Firebase's Transactions to make it atomic?

**A: No, you can use [multi-location update](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) using AngularFire2. Good answer [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/380#issuecomment-234666818)**